# What is the meaning of "error on" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

I cannot comprehend the phrase "error on" in this sentence:

> For simplicity, I will focus on real-valued matrices and vectors, and I **error on** the side of intuitive examples rather than generalizations.

from this article: [A Geometrical Understanding of Matrices](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2018/10/24/matrices/#:%7E:text=When%20we%20perform%20matrix%20multiplication,are%20the%20components%20of%20x.) by [an American](https://www.linkedin.com/in/gwgundersen/).

I googled and found that error can be [used as a verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/is-errored-correct-usage), but it seems that in the above sentence "error on" has nothing to do with "error". Is it slang? What does it mean?

Comment: I'm guessing the author (or his editor) got tripped up by grammar correcting software.

Comment: @BillOnne: Any grammar correcting software that steered the user towards using the noun ***error*** instead of the verb ***err*** in the cited context would be worse than useless! So I seriously doubt that's the "explanation".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You would think that software would not add grammar errors. But you would be disappointed. Much grammar software is very horrible. It's especially bad when authors start leaning on it and stop doing their own proof reading. But I'm guessing the software offered choices and the author quickly clicked the wrong one, the software accepted it, and the error was then cemented in.

Comment: @BillOnne: I wouldn't *deliberately* use any ***grammar correcting*** software. I don't go out of my way to disable ***spell checking*** features if they're automatically included in some software I'm using anyway. So my Brave browser is checking the words as I write in this comment box, and it's already "red-underline-alerted" me *twice* that I had finger trouble and typed ***p*** instead of ***o*** in ***software***. But it's perfectly happy to let me type ***err errs erring erred*** here because they're all valid words. Explicitly programmed syntax checking is a waste of time, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a mistake.
Merriam-Webster shows *error* as a noun, while *err* is the related verb:

[M-W *error*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/error) 
noun

[M-W *err*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/err)
intransitive verb
to make a mistake
*erred on the side of caution*

M-W's example above shows the usual use of *err on the side of*.
The sense is that the speaker is more cautious than not, even if that results in some error.

In your example, the speaker is claiming to use more intuitive examples, while admitting that doing so may introduce some error.